# Querying features in mapbox which are not visible

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox map with lots of geometries (100 000+ features).

I'd like to draw a rectangle and select features, which belong to the bounds drawn out.
Mapbox provides such feature via `queryRenderedFeatures()`

Something like this example:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/using-box-queryrenderedfeatures/

The selection is made by this code snippet:

```
const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(bbox, {
     layers: ['myFirstLayer', 'mySecondLayer', 'myThirdLayer']
});
```

This one selects only features, that are currently rendered.  In my scenario all my layers have a minzoom layout property set, to display only at certain zoom.

But after drawing the rectangle, I'd like to select all features which are on my map - either visible or invisible.

Does mabpox provide this functionality, or do I have to do that on my own?

Comment: I guess since you have that many features, you are retrieving the data from a tileset?

Comment: Not at the time. Currently its loaded as a geojson file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the dataset loaded as a GeoJSON, I would simply query it directly.

Use [flatbush](https://github.com/mourner/flatbush) to set up a spatial index of all your features, then call `.search()` to perform the bounding box query.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggest, but I used d3.quadtree. Is the flatbush package faster/better?

Comment: Whether it's faster/better isn't really relevant to the question.

Comment: turf.js can also achieve this using https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointsWithinPolygon